# How to make links clickable with negative z-index?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I am  using `drop-down` menu in my header for notification, but when drop down opens all the div's behind that are visible then I gave `z-index` to all the divs but the links on those div's are not clickable now!

drop-down div CSS:

```
.drop-down{
   overflow:scroll;
   overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

and the div's behind it are

```
#main-div{
   z-index:-1;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess that the negative `z-index` places the links **underneath** the body.

Use a positive `z-index`, for example `10` on the element that should be at the back and `20` on the element that should be in front.