# How to make link clickable when using z-index without turning all other elements z-index negative?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I'm trying to make a drop-down box with a button and a toolbar so that my drop-down will be behind the toolbar but in front of my main element. The problem is that to do this I use z-index with negative value because using positive value on the toolbar will cause it to get behind my drop-box due to positioning and hierarchy.

I know that if I'll go and change the z-index of elements in my DOM to smaller negative values (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428293/7312886)) it will make my links clickable again, but this seems to be a very inefficient way of solving the issue. Plus, I'd rather not mess with the toolbar and break it different elements for each button as this can cause a lot of issues with responsiveness in the future. Please take a look at the JFiddler link below.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#btn2').on('click', function() {
  console.log('Click!');
  var element = document.getElementById("sub-memu");
  element.classList.toggle("show");
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.toolbar {
  height: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, red);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  position: relative;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

button {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#sub-memu {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(0px, -140%);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

main {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: calc(100% - 40px - 20px - 20px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.show {
  transform: translate(0px, 25px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class='toolbar'>
    <div class='buttons'>
      <button id='btn1'>
        Button 1
      </button>
      <div class='btn-wrapper'>
        <button id='btn2'>
          Button 2
        </button>
        <div id='sub-memu' class='subMenu'>
          <a href='#'>Can you click me?</a>
          <a href='#'>Can you click me?</a>
          <a href='#'>Can you click me?</a>
          <a href='#'>Can you click me?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>
    This is my main element.
    <a href="#">You should be able to click me</a>.
  </main>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atb8yq6e/1/

What I'm trying to achieve is the same behavior as can bee seen in my JSFiddle link (drop-down box lowering from behind the navigation bar but in front of my main content) but with active links, without going through my DOM tree and changing every overlapping element's z-index to lower number.

Thank you all in advance,
Lior.

Comment: what the problem change `z-index` in `#sub-memu` to  `z-index:1` ?

Comment: @VadimHulevich Hi Vadim, doing as you suggested will cause the the menu to move in front of the navigation bar instead of behind it. Please see my question "... drop-down box lowering _from behind the navigation bar_ but in front of my main content ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index` to body element to make sure you create a stacking context and avoid having the element going behind it:

```js
$('#btn2').on('click', function() {
  console.log('Click!');
  var element = document.getElementById("sub-memu");
  element.classList.toggle("show");
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.toolbar {
  height: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, red);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  position: relative;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

button {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#sub-memu {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(0px, -140%);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

main {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: calc(100% - 40px - 20px - 20px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.show {
  transform: translate(0px, 25px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class='toolbar'>
    <div class='buttons'>
      <button id='btn1'>
        Button 1
      </button>
      <div class='btn-wrapper'>
        <button id='btn2'>
          Button 2
        </button>
        <div id='sub-memu' class='subMenu'>
          <a href='#'>Can you click me?</a>
          <a href='#'>Can you click me?</a>
          <a href='#'>Can you click me?</a>
          <a href='#'>Can you click me?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>
    This is my main element.
    <a href="#">You should be able to click me</a>.
  </main>
</body>
```

Related: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

Comment: Hi Temani, I tried your answer and it seems to work, although it is a bit on the side of creating stacking context and assigning z-index and positioning for every relevant element in the hierarchy, which is something I hoped to avoid. Do you have an opinion on Saeed Taran's suggestion below?

Comment: @LiorLavi *it is a bit on the side of creating stacking context and assigning z-index and positioning for every relevant element in the hierarchy* --> I only added z-index and position to body element, that's all. Why you need to do this for other elements?

Comment: In my actual code the structure of the DOM is more complex and has more levels so simply adding the z-index to the body doesn't seem to cut it. But adding it to the relevant elements such as the #app and my .container-fluid indeed solved it.

Comment: @LiorLavi *In my actual code the structure of the DOM is more complex* --> if we don't have your **real** code then we cannot provide you with an accurate solution. I provided the best solution considering the code I have and this doesn't mean it's the best solution for any kind of code or DOM structure. If I see your real code I may provide a complete different solution.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The thing is my code is part of a Laravel project and l didn't think it make sense to drop it all here as it split across multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

add this codes to your css:

```
html{
  pointer-events:none;
}
body *{
  pointer-events:initial;
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hL32e6cz/

Comment: Hi Saeed, I tried your suggestion and while it works on JSFiddler, it doesn't seem to be the case in my actual code :(
For some reason, in my actual code it still seems that the underlining elements overlap and cover my child elements. I tried Temani Afif's suggestion and it seems to work, although your solution is cleaner. Too bad I can't make it work in my project as well :(

Comment: this should work because the only thing this code do is making the body and html tags to transfer click event to their behind where your negative zindex elements are placed

Comment: Interesting.. I'll branch out my git branch and test it again as soon as I get the chance and update you on the results. Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Simply set `z-index` to `1` instead on your `#sub-memu` (should probably be menu?), and remove the `z-index` value on `main`.

Comment: Hi Tidsoptimisten, doing as you suggested will cause the the menu to move in front of the navigation bar instead of behind it. Please see my question "... drop-down box lowering _from behind the navigation bar_ but in front of my main content ..."

Comment: My bad, I missed that part!